# show create table returns empty result

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a MySQL backup script, and i'm having problem with the "SHOW CREATE TABLE". 
On some servers, when i run the script, DbPDO fails to return resource from the query.
It fails on quite random tables.
When i run single  "show create table" for the failing table in phpmyadmin , the result is ok ... 
But on my localhost I never managed to reproduce the problem.
It seems the problem is not in the MySQL engines , both InnoDB and MyISAM tables fails. 
How could i trace the problem ?

Comment: failing how? your query call returns false? script crashes? you get back an empty result set?

Comment: Privilege issues? Reserved words issues? Any chance for an example of a 'failing' table? Do you mean `PDO`, or is `DbPDO` some kind of wrapper lib?

Comment: query returns false. Yes i'm using a wrapper for handling different libs - mysql, mysqli, PDO

Comment: Have a look at the [EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html)

Comment: also, i don't think the problems is privilege issue nor reserved word , every table name is put between ``.
i'm not sure how to give an example of failing table, they are quite random

Comment: Please show the code you are running.

Comment: Actually it wasnt database problem. I was using ajax to run the backup script and on some servers there was a suppressed  error throwing and overflowing the output , which causes faulty requests.